# How to fix deprecated 'buildDir' reference in Gradle 8.5 for simple tasks?

Tags: gradle

Gradle version 8.5, using Groovy scripting.

Simple task:

```
tasks.register('copyDependencyLibs', Copy) {
  into "$buildDir/libs/dependencies"
  from configurations.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Gives warning `'buildDir' is deprecated`.

This question is just "what is the simplest way to remove the deprecation warning for a basic path reference?"

The Gradle doco says the string interpolation should be replaced by three lines of code:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#project_builddir

That seems like huge overkill.

My primary concern is maintaining brevity and preserving functionality with minimal changes.
Ideally, I'm looking for the simplest code that replaces the deprecated reference.

I don't believe this question is a duplicate - other SO questions I've found are asking about more complicated situations (how to set the `buildDir`, how to use it in an `allprojects` closure pattern, etc.) and don't have simple answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even shorter is to use:

```
into layout.buildDirectory.dir('libs/dependencies')
```

Maybe worth remembering that Gradle's objective in changing the API is to make access to such a directory lazy, so that the build doesn't break if the build directory is changed somewhere else in the build. Hence why we are now calling methods instead of accessing properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest code I could come up with that seems to work:

`into layout.buildDirectory.get().dir("libs/dependencies")`

It's a bit verbose, but not too bad.  I'll get used to I guess, if this is really the best way to do it.

One thing that concerns me though - is that there might be some subtle way that this is "incorrect" and won't work in more complicated build scenarios or something?
Otherwise, why would the upgrade instructions give the three lines of code the way they do?

Comment: Of the three lines of code you reference, only the first is about setting a property. The other two are about accessing a `Provider` property, so the documentation is somewhat confusing. So still only one line of code to set it.